# Return Match with respect to Occurrence ,Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have many strings (in series format) and a list of words in csv format. I need to match the expression and return the word that is at the top in the csv . For example : i have them as

```
Hsr layout  
aecs layout  
garden layout  
k aecs layout
```

and suppose my string contains :

```
str1 = "room no 135 chancery hotel,block k aecs layout"
```

Since `aecs layout` occurs above `k aecs layout` , i would want the expression to match `aecs layout` . My code returns the latter. How could i prioritize it?

My code:

```
str1 = "room no 135 chancery hotel,block k aecs layout" 
layouts_string1 =r'({})'.format('|'.join(['hsr layout','aecs layout','garden layout','k aecs layout']))
layout1_re = re.compile(layouts_string1)
ms = layout1_re.search(str1)
print ms.group()
```

but this returns `"k aecs layout"` . How would i get the one i.e `aecs layout` which comes first in the '|' expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `k aecs layout` matches, rather than `aecs layout`, is because the `k` letter comes before the `a` letter, and thus the regex finds the match on the `k` rather than the later `a`.

One workaround is to write a loop:

```
str1 = "room no 135 chancery hotel,block k aecs layout"
for match in ['hsr layout','aecs layout','garden layout','k aecs layout']:
    layout1_re = re.compile(match)
    ms = layout1_re.search(str1)
    if ms:
        print ms.group()
        break

Out:
>>> 
aecs layout
```

The reason you have to loop through multiple times is because: if you want to prioritise certain matches, you have to check to the end of the string for the highest priority match before you can check the string with other matches.

Your use case is actually quite simple, though, and if I may suggest a simpler solution without regex:

```
str1 = "room no 135 chancery hotel,block k aecs layout"
for match in ['hsr layout','aecs layout','garden layout','k aecs layout']:
    if match in str1:
        print match
        break
```